# Resubmit binary from other system

Tags: iphone, binary, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I developed a iphone application and submitted on iTunes. but after this i lost the system so now i want to submit updated version of this application on itunes from other system. so plz suggest me how i install the old provisioning profile certificate on other system. or revoke the previous provisioning profile.

If i revoke the old provisioning profile then application that are already installed on other devices that will work or not work? please suggest how i upload new binary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to submit a binary from ANY system you need:

1. the distribution certificate from the keychain WITH private key
2. the app store provisioning profile for this app
3. then you can build&archive the app
4. you have to create a new version on ITC
5. then in Xcode organizer you first validate then submit the app, chosing the correct provisioning profile

In case you don't have item 1 then you have to create a new certificate via the keychain utility and website.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, as Cocoanetics says, you’ll need to create a new developer certificate through the iOS Provisioning Portal, following the same procedure—using Keychain Access’s “request a certificate from a certificate authority” malarkey—that you used to create it originally. You’ll then have to recreate your development and distribution provisioning profiles using that new certificate.

To avoid this kind of problem in future, it’s a good idea to use Xcode’s “Export Developer Profile” feature: it creates a single encrypted package for you that contains the private key, certificates, and provisioning profiles that you have on your system. You can then easily back up that single file to a flash drive or online storage service or whatever, and re-import it later if you somehow lose your data again. To export the profile, go to the Organizer (Cmd-Ctrl-O in Xcode 3.x, Cmd-Shift-2 and then click on the “Devices” tab in Xcode 4) and select “Developer Profile” from the left-hand sidebar.